# MongoDB or MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mysql-python

I have a question about making the decision whether to use MySQL database or Mongo database, the problem with my decision is that I am highly depending on these things:

- I want to select records between two dates (period)

However is this possible?

My Application won't do any complex queries, just basic crud. It has Facebook integration so sometimes I got to JOIN the users table at the current setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL(SQL) or MongoDB(NoSQL), both can work for your needs. but idea behind using RDBMS/NoSQL is the requirement of your application

- if your application care about speed and no relation between the data is necessary and your data schema changes very frequently, you can choose MongoDB, faster since no joins needed, every data is a stored as document
- else, go for MySQL

Answer (score 3):

Either DB will allow you to filter between dates and I wouldn't use that requirement to make the decision. Some questions you should answer:

1. Do you need to store your data in a relational system, like MySQL? Relational databases are better at cross entity joining.
2. Will your data be very complicated, but you will only make simple queries (e.g. by an ID), if so MongoDB may be a better fit as storing and retrieving complex data is a cinch.
3. Who and where will you be querying the data from? MySql uses SQL for querying, which is a much more well known skill than mongo's JSON query syntax.

These are just three questions to ask. In order to make a recommendation, we'll need to know more about your application?

Comment: My Application won't do any complex queries, just basic crud. It has Facebook integration so sometimes I got to JOIN the users table at the current setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for range queries in MongoDB - yes, Mongo supports those. For date-based range queries, have a look at this: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/